# Problem on running TurtleBot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am currently install ROS Kinetic and try to run  a robot on the Stage Simulator. I installed TurtleBot and run the following command:
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
But I got this error:
while processing /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml'
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Can any body help me what I missed to do and how can I solve this issue!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248759/problem-on-running-turtlebot/) by [Elnaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28601/elnaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the following in the turtlebot_in_stage.launch file solved the problem for me:

---

Originally posted by [gdepaepe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28831/gdepaepe/) with karma: 66 on 2016-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-01-17**:
This bug was [fixed in the source](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/commit/9020a8cee1d151655278eadb927b37c664d4e4dc), but the fix hasn't been released yet.

**Comment by [Carrie Yan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30264/carrie-yan/) on 2017-05-08**:
how to open the launch file, i cannot find the directory

**Comment by [Carrie Yan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30264/carrie-yan/) on 2017-05-08**:
Gotcha! use $roscd turtlebox_stage and then cd to launch, use $sudo gedit to edit the .launch file